# @ConditionalOnBean not being triggered even though Bean exists in SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, integration-testing

I have the following AutoConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyAutoConfiguration {
  @AutoConfigureAfter(MockMvcAutoConfiguration.class)
  class MyNestedAutoConfiguration {
    @ConditionalOnBean(MockMvc.class)
    @Bean
    AugmentedMockMvc augmentedMockMvc(MockMvc mockMvc) {
      return new AugmentedMockMvc(mockMvc);
    }
  }
}
```

The class is properly registered in spring.factories, and it is imported as a maven dependency in my Spring Boot application. My Spring Boot application looks like the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBootApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootApp.class, args);
  }
}
```

Finally, I have an integration test that is defined like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MySpringBootApp.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {MyInitializer.class})
class MyTest {
  @Autowired
  private AugmentedMockMvc augmentedMockMvc;
}
```

`MyInitializer` can be ignored, it doesn't do anything meaningful here, but it is needed and therefore I need to use both `@SpringBootTest` and `@ContextConfiguration`.

**The issue is the following**: With this setup, the augmentedMockMvc Bean is not created because it does not match the `@ConditionalOnBean(MockMvc.class)` condition.

I tried two things:

- Adding `classes = {MockMvcAutoConfiguration.class}` to `@ContextConfiguration`. This works fine and fixes the issue, the augmentedMockMvc Bean is now properly registered
- Removing the `@ConditionalOnBean(MockMvc.class)` annotation from the Bean creation. Weirdly enough, this also works! The MockMvc Bean is actually there, but it is not discovered by Spring when evaluating the `@ConditionalOnBean` annotation.

I don't understand why the MockMvc Bean is not found by the `@ConditionalOnBean(MockMvc.class)` even though the Bean exists unless I specifically put the class in the `@ContextConfiguration`, I would think that having `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` on `MyTest` should be enough for the `MockMvcAutoConfiguration.class` class to be in the context

Comment: Does injecting/autowiring a `MockMvc` bean normally work (Can you inject a `MockMvc` instance in your test) or does that result in an exception as well? What happens when removing the `@ContextConfiguration`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@AutoConfigureAfter` only works on a top-level class that is listed in `spring.factories`. You haven't shown your `spring.factories` file, but assuming that it lists `MyAutoConfiguration`, that's the class on which `@AutoConfigureAfter` should be placed.

Comment: Indeed this was the issue, we were actually misusing `@AutoConfigureAfter` and `@AutoConfigureBefore` in our codebase, which led me to think it would work in nested classes. Thank you very much for the quick answer, Andy.